# Cell formatting in Grid Geometry manager

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have this code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class Application:
    def __init__(self, master):#Change to game class when combining code
        self.master = master#remove when combining code
        self.frame_Canvas = ttk.Frame(self.master, width = 600, height = 600)
        self.frame_Canvas.pack(side = 'left')
        self.frame_Canvas.pack_propagate(False)
        self.frame_Canvas.grid_propagate(False)
        self.hangman = Canvas(self.frame_Canvas, width = 600, height = 600,
                              background = 'white').pack()
        self.FullName = ttk.Label(self.frame_Canvas, text = "Full Name", background = 'white')#full name will be entered here
        self.FullName.config(font=("TkDefaultFont", 20))
        self.FullName.place(x = 10, y = 10)
        self.frame_Interact = ttk.Frame(self.master, width = 200, height = 600)
        self.frame_Interact.pack(side = 'right')
        self.frame_Interact.pack_propagate(False)
        self.frame_Interact.grid_propagate(False)
        self.QuestionLabel = ttk.Label(self.frame_Interact, text = "Question:")
        self.QuestionLabel.config(font=("TkDefaultFont", 20))
        self.QuestionLabel.grid(column = 0, row = 0)
        self.QuestionShow = Text(self.frame_Interact, height=1, width=8)#input question here 
        self.QuestionShow.config(font=("TkDefaultFont", 20))
        self.QuestionShow.grid(column = 0, row = 1)#FIX THE FORMATTING OF QUESTION, GRID CELL TO LEFT, NOT BIG ENOUGTH?

        self.AnswerEntry = ttk.Entry(self.frame_Interact, width = 10)#do later




def main():            

    root = Tk()
    root.wm_title("Hangman")
    Menu = Application(root)
    root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    root.iconbitmap("windowicon.ico")
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

I dont know why, but the Answer box and label on the right side of my tkinter GUI is on the left side of its frame. I want it in the center. Does anyone know a way to frix it, or any improvements for the code so far. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways you can do this, first way will to be to use `.pack()` instead of `.grid()` since pack is very easy to use and does the aligning for you automatically.

So you can just replace:

```
self.QuestionLabel.grid(column = 0, row = 0)
# and
self.QuestionShow.grid(column = 0, row = 1)
```

With:

```
self.QuestionLabel.pack()
# and 
self.QuestionLShow.pack()
```

This way isn't recommended for your situation whatsoever, since that will involve mixing pack and grid together which could cause future errors in your code.

As Bryan Oakley said:
*it will cause errors immediately, if the widgets share the same parent. It won't ever cause problems if the widgets have different parents.*

You should instead do this:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class Application:
    def __init__(self, master):#Change to game class when combining code
        self.master = master#remove when combining code
        self.frame_Canvas = ttk.Frame(self.master, width = 600, height = 600)
        self.frame_Canvas.pack(side = 'left')
        self.frame_Canvas.pack_propagate(False)
        self.frame_Canvas.grid_propagate(False)
        self.hangman = Canvas(self.frame_Canvas, width = 600, height = 600,
                              background = 'white').pack()
        self.FullName = ttk.Label(self.frame_Canvas, text = "Full Name", background = 'white')#full name will be entered here
        self.FullName.config(font=("TkDefaultFont", 20))
        self.FullName.place(x = 10, y = 10)
        self.frame_Interact = ttk.Frame(self.master, width = 200, height = 600)
        self.frame_Interact.pack(side = 'right')
        self.frame_Interact.pack_propagate(False)
        self.frame_Interact.grid_propagate(False)
        Grid.columnconfigure(self.frame_Interact, 0, weight=1) # NOTE, THIS CHANGED
        self.QuestionLabel = ttk.Label(self.frame_Interact, text = "Question:")
        self.QuestionLabel.config(font=("TkDefaultFont", 20))
        self.QuestionLabel.grid(column = 0, row = 0)
        self.QuestionShow = Text(self.frame_Interact, height=1, width=8)
        self.QuestionShow.config(font=("TkDefaultFont", 20))
        self.QuestionShow.grid(column = 0, row = 1)

def main():            
    root = Tk()
    root.wm_title("Hangman")
    Menu = Application(root)
    root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    root.iconbitmap("windowicon.ico")
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    main()
```

By adding `Grid.columnconfigure(self.frame_Interact, 0, weight=1)` it will help grid know how to allocate extra space. so that the label will try to take up the whole column. The same goes for rows if you're wondering, you can add `Grid.rowconfigure(self.frame_Interact, 0, weight=1)` to make the widgets fill the whole row.

And for some improvements to your code, you should change this line:

```
self.hangman = Canvas(self.frame_Canvas, width = 600, height = 600,
                          background = 'white').pack()

# to
self.hangman = Canvas(self.frame_Canvas, width = 600, height = 600, background = 'white')
self.hangman.pack()
```

Or else `self.hangman` will be `None`, as it is in your code.

Comment: re _"mixing pack and grid together which could cause future errors"_ - correction: it _will_ cause errors immediately, if the widgets share the same parent. It won't ever cause problems if the widgets have different parents.

Comment: Also, _"it will add some weight to your frame so that the label will try to take up the whole column"_ - that's not what weight does. The weight helps grid know how to allocate extra space.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive abccd and Bryan Oakley. I will try that out and hopefully get the desired results. You've been a big help.

Comment: comprehensive explanation*